# Reading data only when present

Tags: matlab, serial-port, scanf

I'm trying to read the data from the COM3 port.
I'm using this code:

```
in = fscanf(s);
    if(in == 'A')
        fclose(s);
        break;
    end
```

The problem is that when no data is sent to the com3 port, the `fscanf()` will wait for a certain time interval and then give a timeout.

Is there a way to read data only when it is present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Read only when data present

You can read out the `BytesAvailable`-property of the serial object `s` to know how many bytes are in the buffer ready to be read:

```
bytes = get(s,'BytesAvailable');    % using getter-function
bytes = s.BytesAvailable;           % using object-oriented-addressing
```

Then you can check the value of `bytes` to match your criteria. Assuming a char is 1 byte, then you can check for this easily before reading the buffer.

```
if (bytes >= 1)
     in = fscanf(s);
     % do the handling of 'in' here
end
```

### Minimize the time to wait

You can manually set the `Timeout`-property of the serial object `s` to a lower value to continue execution earlier as the default timeout.

```
set(s,'Timeout',1);       % sets timeout to 1 second (default is 10 seconds)
```

Most likely you will get the following warning:

> Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was
>   reached..

It can be suppressed by executing the following command before `fscanf`.

```
warning('off','MATLAB:serial:fscanf:unsuccessfulRead');
```

**Here is an example:**

```
s = serial('COM3');

set(s,'Timeout',1);       % sets timeout to 1 second (default is 10 seconds)

fopen(s);

warning('off','MATLAB:serial:fscanf:unsuccessfulRead');
in = fscanf(s);
warning('on','MATLAB:serial:fscanf:unsuccessfulRead');

if(in == 'A')
    fclose(s);
    break;
end
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, thanks, thanks!